# How to remove encryption from harddrive in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: encryption

Greetings I have "inherited" a Ubuntu 12.04 system installed on a Sun server.

Judging by the output of the `history` command the system is broken from all the `./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install` commands, replacing most of the software with some custom versions that apt is not aware of.

I have backed up all the data and I want to make a clean and functional installation but when I tried to reformat via a Live CD it spit out an I/O error. I booted back into Ubuntu and fsck'ed every partition (remounted / read-only before fsck); there was no corruption on the hard disk. The only logical thing I can assume is that it's encrypted and judging from the `ecryptfs-kthread` process it seems that way. How can I decrypt the whole harddisk in order to reformat and install everything clean?